# Why does Entity Framework always create an additional foreign key column on migration?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, ef-code-first

I will start with code. Created these 2 entities:

```
    public class Product
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<RelatedProduct> RelatedProducts { get; set; }        
    }

    public class RelatedProduct
    {
        [Key, Column(Order=0), ForeignKey("Product")]
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 1), ForeignKey("RelatedProduct")]
        public int RelatedProductId { get; set; }

        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
        public virtual Product RelatedProduct { get; set; }
    }
```

Then when I run `add-migration`, it produced this output:

```
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Product",
            c => new
                {
                    Id = c.Int(nullable: false, identity: true),
                    ProductName = c.String(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.Id);

        CreateTable(
            "dbo.RelatedProduct",
            c => new
                {
                    ProductId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    RelatedProductId = c.Int(nullable: false),
                    Product_Id = c.Int(),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => new { t.ProductId, t.RelatedProductId })
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Products", t => t.ProductId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Products", t => t.RelatedProductId, cascadeDelete: true)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.Product", t => t.Product_Id)
            .Index(t => t.ProductId)
            .Index(t => t.RelatedProductId)
            .Index(t => t.Product_Id);
```

Why is there this 3rd column `Product_Id`?

I expected 2 columns only

Comment: Third FK column, because you have `ICollection<RelatedProduct0> RelatedProducts` at `Product0` class declaration.

Comment: Hi @SlavaUtesinov, wouldn't it be enough to use RelatedProductId instead?
or how to force EF to use just these two FKs ('ProductId' & 'RelatedProductId')?

Comment: You should remove `ICollection<RelatedProduct0> RelatedProducts` or add `Product0 product0` with `int product0Id`.

Comment: sorry @SlavaUtesinov my mistake by suffixing with 0. I updated the code. a `Product` has many `RelatedProduct`s. In `RelatedProduct` I already defined 2 FKs (ProductId and RelatedProductId) which both refer to Products. But still, EF created new column called Product_Id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add second collection of `RelatedProduct` to `Product` class declaration and annotate both of them with `InversePropertyAttribute`. As you have two FKs, you also should have two collections for proper mappings, without it side effects like third `Product_Id` FK will occur:

```
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProductName { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("RelatedProduct")]
    public virtual ICollection<RelatedProduct> RelatedProducts { get; set; }        
    [InverseProperty("Product")]
    public virtual ICollection<RelatedProduct> Products { get; set; }        
}
```